# AngularJS Логическая ошибка

Tags: angularjs

Друзья, вот вьюшка:

```
<div ng-repeat="event in item">
{{event.date}}
{{event.name}}
{{event.number}}
 <div ng-if="event.class == 'image'">
  <div ng-init="record(event.rid)">
   <div ng-repeat="rec in records"
     {{rec.filename}}
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Но у меня множество элементов, где `event.class == 'image'` и records ссылается на одно и тоже. Как поправить этот баг? Всем спасибо!

Comment: добавь в вопрос код функции `record`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше возвращайте список `records` из функции `record(event.rid)` чем использовать `ng-init`.

```
<div ng-repeat="event in item">
{{event.date}}
{{event.name}}
{{event.number}}
 <div ng-if="event.class == 'image'">
  <div>
   <div ng-repeat="rec in record(event.rid)"
     {{rec.filename}}
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```